# Two similar limit problems

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have two limit problems which are quite similar, so I've put them both into this post.

1. $((4^{10}+2^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}})$
2. $((3n^{2}+n)^{\frac{1}{n}})$

Attempt:

For 1, I'm not sure if this is permissible. I know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x^{n}+y^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = \max\{x,y\}$. Obviously $4^{10}$ is a constant so it's not quite in the same form, but I believe it is still okay to use this result, and so the limit is $2$.

For 2, I've got $((3n^{2}+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}) = (n(3n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}})$, but then I'm not too sure how to proceed.

I also thought of taking the log and proceeding that way, however in the notes I'm learning from they haven't covered l'hopital yet, so I'm trying to not use it.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean $((3n^{2}+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}) = (n(3n+1))^{\frac{1}{n}}$ ?

Comment: Yes typo, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one we have

$$(4^{10}+2^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=2\left(\frac{4^{10}}{2^n}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 2\cdot 1^0 =2$$

and

$$(3n^{2}+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\log(3n^{2}+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}=e^{\frac{\log (3n^2+n) }{n}}\to e^0= 1$$

recall indeed that $\frac{\log n}n \to 0$ and therefore

$$\frac{\log (3n^2+n) }{n}\le \frac{\log (3n^2+6n+3) }{n}=\frac{\log (3(n+1)^2) }{n}=\frac{2\log (n+1)+\log 3 }{n}=$$

$$=2\frac{n+1}n\frac{\log (n+1) }{n+1}+\frac{\log 3}n\to 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 0 + 0 =0$$

As an alternative for the second we can also use that

$$n^\frac1n \le(3n^{2}+n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \le (3n^{2}+n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(4n^{2})^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

and conclude in a similar way by squeeze theorem.

Comment: For the first one, where do you get  the factor of $2$ from in the first equality? For the second one where does the $2$ in $2 \frac{n+1}{n}$ come from? As an aside, how would one prove the result about $ \frac{\log n}{n} \to 0$ (I'll have a go myself using definition of null sequence / convergence).  Thanks (again!).

Comment: @AnalysisLearner It is a simple step $$(4^{10}+2^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\left(2^n \left(\frac{4^{10}}{2^n}+1\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(2^n)^\frac1n\left(\frac{4^{10}}{2^n}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=2\left(\frac{4^{10}}{2^n}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: @AnalysisLearner ALso the second one is a simple step $$\frac{2\log (n+1)}{n}=2\frac{n+1}n\frac{\log (n+1) }{n+1}$$ I've noticed now tere is a small typo, I fix that.

Comment: @AnalysisLearner A way to prove that is by $ \frac{\log x}{x} \to 0$ which by $x=e^y \to \infty$ becomes $ \frac{\log e^y}{e^y}=\frac y{e^y} \to 0$ .

Comment: @AnalysisLearner Refer also to the [related OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2017291/505767).

Comment: that makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2+\varepsilon)^n=\infty$ and therefroe $(2+\varepsilon)^n>4^{10}$, if $n\gg1$. But then, if $n$ is large enough,$$(2^n)^{1/n}<(4^{10}+2^n)^{1/n}<\bigl((2+\varepsilon)^n+2^n\bigr)^{1/n}.$$Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2^n)^{1/n}=2$ and$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl((2+\varepsilon)^n+2^n\bigr)^{1/n}=\max\{2+\varepsilon,2\}=2+\varepsilon,$$it is easy now to prove that the limit of your sequence is $2$.

For the other sequence, you can use the fact that $3n^2<3n^2+n<4n^2$ and that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(3n^2)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(4n^2)^{1/n}=1.$$

Comment: We can use any constant $>1$ instead of $2+\varepsilon$. Then you don't need the limit trick.

Comment: I mean the limit $\varepsilon\to0$. The limit argument for large $n$ is good.